# How can I add intermittent voice chat to a Unity multiplayer game?

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I'm looking to make a multiplayer horror game with one of the main mechanics being the game's internal voice chat.

Currently I plan on making it cut in and out so that the players (being on opposite ends of the map from each other) will lose verbal contact with each other.

I planned on using Unity. Do you know how I could go about making this work?

Comment: I changed the question to ask for general advise, not for a recommendation.

Comment: Well, you could make the audio objects that output the player's voice is 3D sound, and each player has an audio listener. That way, as distance increases, volume decreaes.